# What is the name of this fallacy (if it is one)

Tags: fallacies

So I stumbled on a discussion that went a little like this:

> **Person A:** "Something has happened to a family member and has been hospitalized, please be aware so it does not happen to you"
>
> **Person B:** "please provide proof that X has happened to your family member, otherwise your warning of precaution is fear mongering"
>
> **A:** "I am not going to provide you proof. `(because irrefutable proof to person B would be along the lines of showing personal information, like hospitalization documents, and probably ends up shifting goalposts)`"
>
> **B:** "Well then your claim of a personal event is false"

I cant quite figure out what person **B** is doing here, but there is certainly some kind of fallacy going on here.

Basically B is demanding unreasonable evidence from A, on the other hand it sounds like it's borderline reasonable because the proof can be provided and depending on the context of the discussion, the fact that it would reveal personal information would not be a problem.

Comment: yeah i encounter this a lot. i'd suggest person B is being disingenuous, but yeah that itself is no informal fallacy

Comment: Non sequitur is one. The conclusion person B has made is not capable of being deducted correctly from the information given. This also fits a variation of the Argument from ignorance fallacy: if you can't prove x then x is false.  Note: there can be several fallacies in a single instance. Also be aware different people might use slightly different names for the same fallacy.

Comment: "Either you have a proof you can give or you are fear mongering" is a [false dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma) (the proof may be inaccessible for privacy reasons, as you point out, etc.) combined with an [*ad hominem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem), attacking opponent's motives. But it is a different matter if the speaker has a history of crying wolf and playing fast and loose with facts, making the implicit accusation more plausible.

Comment: It’s not that X is known to be false, but there is no evidence to evaluate A’s claim one way or the other. To believe A based solely on the fact that A said so is to appeal to authority.

Comment: Could there be a consensus that this example committed multiple fallacies and not just a single one?

Comment: https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Just_asking_questions this seems rather fitting